# Hibernate NoMethod Error in Java

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting an error in hibernate and failing to know its origin

stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindDefaults(Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Mappings;)V
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1360)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1826)
    at com.BiddingSystem.server.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

Comment: What is your scenario, what is your code, what are you trying to do, ...? Many questions that need answers. I highly doubt that someone will be able to help you from an exception stack trace.

Comment: And even the Stack Trace won't help until you say which hibernate version you are using

Comment: Actually, hibernate version seems to be 3.6.0 (at least the line numbers match)

Comment: ya hibernate 3.6, it is that I was not getting any error, then suddently strangely getting this error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the Hibernate Annotations Jar is of the wrong version.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue with Hibernate version 3.6.0.Final. I had hibernate-annotations.jar version 3.5.6-Final in my classpath. Removing that from the POM fixed the issue as hibernate-core version 3.6.0.Final already has the correct class.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an issue opened in hibernate site.the solution seems to be taking latest hibernate jars.

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2245097&sid=57ef81f69c29ed7484680f2bbab9752f

So when you take jar file, please take everything related and make sure it is latest.